# Custom plugin, have to click ok twice?

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Been trying to create my own plugin and managed to get a basic one sorted.

I've added a custom text field so that I can add custom attributes to an element in this format **{"data-title":"My data title","data-id":"001"}**.  I can also edit the element and it returns the custom attributes.

This works fine, can add as many as I like.  The trouble is when I want to remove one, I just delete it from the text field and click ok, but I have to click it twice and cannot suss out why.  Here is the code I've got so far, there is probably a much better way to do this, but this kinda works.

```
commit: function(element) {

//core attributes to ignore
var ignoreArr=["href","id","name","data-cke-saved-href","class","style","title"];

//add to ignore Array, attributes to keep
var data=$.parseJSON('['+this.getValue()+']');
if(data) {
    $(data).each(function(i,val){
        $.each(val,function(k,v){
            ignoreArr.push(k);     
        });
    });

}
//alert(ignoreArr);

//remove all uneeded custom attributes first
$.each(element.$.attributes, function(k,v) {
    if(v) { //MOD :: had to add this check in to stop the double click
        if(jQuery.inArray(v.name,ignoreArr)==-1) {
            element.removeAttribute(v.name);                                
        } 
    }
});

//will create custom attributes
if(data) {
    $(data).each(function(i,val){
        $.each(val,function(k,v){
            element.setAttribute(k,v);     
        });
    });
}   //end if data
```

}

The problem seems to be with this line **element.removeAttribute(v.name);**, if I replace it with an alert, all works fine.  Now a double click is not the end of the world, it's just annoying that I cannot figure out why, anyone get a suggestion/fix for this.

Comment: could u debug it and tell what are the result after one click and after two? you might stumble the answer there already.

Comment: that helped thanks, managed to sort it, had an undefined object, just put a check in place and that fixed it.

Comment: glad it helped, u might as well post the answer or delete this question :)

Comment: have modified my original posting with the working code now and highlighted the small correction